# Obtaining Mongolian visa in Vientiane, Laos

Tags: laos, mongolia, embassies, vientiane, consulates

If my Chinese visa application today goes well I'm hoping to then apply for my Mongolian visa here in Vientiane, Laos.

But I can't find the current location or opening hours of the Mongolian embassy here!

Google maps lists the [Mongolian ambassador's residence](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=residence%20loc%3aQ.%20Watnak%20vientiane%20laos&aq=&sll=17.935147,102.617846&sspn=0.002445,0.005493&vpsrc=6&ie=UTF8&hq=residence&hnear=Watnak%20Nyai%20Rd,%20Vientiane,%20Vientiane%20Prefecture,%20Laos&t=m&fll=17.936847,102.61857&fspn=0.004889,0.006899&st=115703629269948245352&rq=1&ev=zi&split=1&ll=17.936847,102.61857&spn=0.004889,0.006899&z=17&iwloc=D), but not the Mongolian embassy.

Various unofficial sites with crappy lists of embassies that fill up Google results give an address that looks like a post office box:

> Mongolian Embassy in Vientiane, Laos
>   Q. Wat Nak Km.3
>   P. O. Box 370
>   Vientiane
>   Laos

This makes me not trust the rest of the information they list. Specifically, the hours that many embassies and consulates accept visa applications is often a lot more restricted compared to their general hours of operation.

There is an [official page for a Mongolian embassy in Laos](http://www.vientiane.mfa.gov.mn/), but it barely functions and its two links to visa application forms are both broken.

The only information I can find online from an actual traveller is [this one from "Linda"](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2212478#19967684) on the Lonely Planet forum from mid 2012, which doesn't offer any details of the embassy's location or visa application hours.

Comment: Call them?   +856-21-315220.

Comment: Or, if you're not in a hurry, go visit the ambassador's residence, the staff there should be able to tell you where the Embassy is.  (Not necessarily in English though...)

Comment: Yeah I'm keeping that as a backup. I've had bad experiences trying to call embassies and consulates before. Sometimes language barrier, sometimes bureaucracy. I would expect ambassadors' residences are not open to random pedestrians visiting. I found it odd that they're in Google Maps - I haven't seen any with signs on them when I've wandered around the area.

Answer (score 5):

The correct address appears to be :

```
KM 3, Thadeua Road
Watnak Village
Sisattanak District
Vientiane
```

This would place it very close to the ambassadors residence, and in the same vicinity as multiple other embassies, including Japan, India, Singapore and Australia (which is at KM4, Thadeua Road).  If you get stuck, I'm sure the staff at the Australia embassy would be able to point you in the correct direction.

As others have already suggested you could call them (+856-21-315220) or email them (   vientiane@mfat.gov.mn or possible embmong@laotel.com)

Comment: Yes I was just wandering around this area while getting misdirected to the Economic Office China Embassy instead of the "regular" China Embassy. While looking for the right one and on my way back I passed the embassies of Australia, Cambodia, Germany, India, Japan, North Korea, and Singapore as well as two or three signed ambassadors' residences I still didn't see anything Mongolian. But as the actual China Embassy's consular section closed while I was waiting at the wrong one, I'll have to go back tomorrow anyway (-:

Comment: It turns out I didn't wander around the block behind the Singapore embassy though. But now due to complications it doesn't look like I'll have time to apply for a Mongolian visa before I head to China )-:

Comment: I can now confirm that the Mongolian embassy is indeed at the same location indicated on Google Maps and the Mongolian ambassador's residence. Basically you head sout down the main road (Thadeua Road), turn left at the first road after the Singapore embassy, then immediately right. There's a sign on the gate with the embassy hours, but no other details. I did not enter on this occasion as my passport is now at the China embassy and I've found that there are Mongolian consulates on my route through China anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  This will be fixed in Google Maps shortly.

Answer (score 4):

there is not much info online so I want to help! I just went to the mongolian embassy in Vientiane. It looks closed but you ring the bell and somebody will come. I just had to fill a form and give my passport, I asked for the quick service and they did it for me at the moment ( had to wait 30min), of course paying double $$. If tou want the normal option it takes 3-5 days. The adress is the one online. Bring cash to pay the visa. Hope it helps. I have spanish passport btw.